# Using angular js to conditionally display HTML, but the CSS is being messed up when i put the HTML code inside ng-if or ng-switch statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I have a grid of div's that I am attempting to color dynamically by checking the value of booleans in ng-if's BUT when i put the code inside the ng-if's the color and css of the div gets messed up.

For example the following code:

```
<div class="rTableCellA" >1</div>
```

Displays a cell that is formatted fine and colored according to the definition of rTableCellA in the CSS. However surrounding this line of code with an ng-if though messes up the color of the cell, with only the left half being colored. Same happens when I surround the code with ng-switch's. WHY?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some actual code would be nice

Comment: <div class="rTableCellA" >1</div>

.rTableCellA { display: table-cell;   padding: 3px 10px;    border: 0.5px solid #999999; background-color: #006bb3; }

Again, the HTML above works fine until I surround it with an ng-if, such as this:

<div ng-if="day1Availability[0] == false">

the background color of the grid gets messed up and only half has the color designated. it looks like the css is being overriden somehow by the ng-if

Comment: Thats like saying: My HTML does not work: `<div>` why? Please show more code, so that we can help

Comment: Try to use `$parent.color` instead of `color`

Comment: I apologize I'm trying to add the code from my comment above to the post as it adds necessary clarification.

Comment: Just try to create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com) so we could actually see the problem.

Comment: Do you mean replace " background-color: #006bb3; "  with " background-$parent.color: #006bb3; " ?

Comment: No no.. I didn't think that you mean to the css in `style` tag.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yomotuhiva/edit?html,output 

this shows the problem! you will see the first cell is half uncolored. if you remove the ng-if around it, it is colored as it should be. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ng-class for your case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .rTable {
        display: table;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .rTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .rTableHeading {
        display: table-header-group;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .rTableHead {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 0.5px solid #999999;
    }
    .rTableCellA {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 0.5px solid #999999;
        background-color: #006bb3;
    }
    .blockedOut {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 0.5px solid #999999;
        background-color: #ff9900;
    }
    .rTableHeading {
        display: table-header-group;
        background-color: #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .rTableFoot {
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .rTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app>


<div class="rTable">
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Monday</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Tuesday</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Wednesday</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Thursday</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Friday</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Saturday</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead">
            <strong>Sunday</strong>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div ng-class="{rTableCellA: a == a}">1</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">2</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">3</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">4</div>
        <div class="blockedOut">5</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">6</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCellA">1</div>
        <div class="blockedOut">2</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">3</div>
        <div class="blockedOut">4</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">5</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">6</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA">8</div>
    </div>
</div </body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/bicidahega/1/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks buddy!! Out of curiosity, can you give a brief summary of why using an ng-if in my original method was not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's not relevant to the `ng-if`. Just add the class `.rTableCellA` to the div with the `ng-if`.

The problem was that the div inside the `ng-if` has the class `.rTableCellA` so it's not "take" the full width because of the `display:table-cell`. Like in the image below:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .rTable {     display: table;     width: 25%; } 
      .rTableRow {     display: table-row; } 
      .rTableHeading {    display: table-header-group;    background-color: #ddd; } 
      .rTableHead {    display: table-cell;    padding: 3px 10px;    border: 0.5px solid #999999; } 
      .rTableCellA { display: table-cell;   padding: 3px 10px;    border: 0.5px solid #999999; background-color: #006bb3; }
      .blockedOut { display: table-cell;   padding: 3px 10px;    border: 0.5px solid #999999; background-color: #ff9900; }
      .rTableHeading {     display: table-header-group;    background-color: #ddd;     font-weight: bold; } 
      .rTableFoot {    display: table-footer-group;    font-weight: bold;    background-color: #ddd; } 
      .rTableBody {     display: table-row-group; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="rTable"> 
      <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Monday</strong>
        </div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Tuesday</strong>
        </div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Wednesday</strong>
        </div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Thursday</strong>
        </div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Friday</strong>
        </div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Saturday</strong>
        </div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">
          <strong>Sunday</strong>
        </div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div ng-if="'a' == 'a'" class="rTableCellA">1</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >2</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >3</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >4</div>
        <div class="blockedOut" >5</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >6</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >8</div>
      </div> 
      <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div class="rTableCellA" >1</div> 
        <div class="blockedOut" >2</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >3</div>
        <div class="blockedOut" >4</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >5</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >6</div>
        <div class="rTableCellA" >8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well my code is meant to decide which class to set the div too based on the result of the ng-if. So if the ng-if is true, set the inside div to class rTableCellA and if it's false, set the class to blockedOut...the class then sets the color as per the CSS. Can I do this? The above code does not allow it unfortunately.

Comment: So you can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: not familiar with it- I'm researching now how I would use it to help me. ty.

Comment: OK. Let me know if you get this true.

Comment: Thanks man. Reading about ng class confused me but the answer above showed me exactly how it works in context and my 2 day problem has been solved!! My first use with stack overflow was a great one, thanks for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure;) I'm glad I could help.